# Rails 5 Ruby 2.5.3 If statements based on ranges of months

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so I'm working on a personal project.

I'm a truck driver and i am building a simple app to track and calculate revenue ect..

What I am trying to do (and there may be a much better way to do it) is highlight what my current active fuel surcharge is based only on a range of months.

In this case its April 1 to Oct 31 and Nov 1 to March 31 this can change as contract requirements dictate ect.

I have an activeDate and endDate column in my database and this is what I have come up with (but doesn't seem to work).

```
**<<index.html.erb>>**

      <tbody>
        <% @fscs.each do |fsc| %>
          <% if Date.today === (fsc.activeDate..fsc.endDate) %>
            <tr>
              <td class="fsc_active"><%= fsc.name %></td>
              <td class="fsc_active"><%= fsc.rate %></td>
              <td class="fsc_active"><%= fsc.activeDate %></td>
              <td class="fsc_active"><%= fsc.endDate %></td>
              <td><%= link_to 'View', fsc %></td>
              <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_fsc_path(fsc) %></td>
              <td><%= link_to 'Delete', fsc, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
            </tr>
          <% else %>
            <tr>
              <td class="fsc_inactive"><%= fsc.name %></td>
              <td class="fsc_inactive"><%= fsc.rate %></td>
              <td class="fsc_inactive"><%= fsc.activeDate %></td>
              <td class="fsc_inactive"><%= fsc.endDate %></td>
              <td><%= link_to 'View', fsc %></td>
              <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_fsc_path(fsc) %></td>
              <td><%= link_to 'Delete', fsc, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
```

Any advice on where I'm going wrong or pointers on how to make this better would be greatly appreciated! please let me know if more information is needed.

EDIT 1: Sorry Only the month matters in this case not the year or day. my apologies for not mentioning this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(fsc.activeDate..fsc.endDate).cover?(Date.today)
```

Instead of using `include?`, use `cover?`. It’s substantially more efficient. `include?` will create a whole array of all possible values to see if the value is in the list. `cover?` just uses the min and max values with a `>=` and `<=` to see if the value is within the range. There are instances where `cover?` is not an applicable replacement for `include?`, but this is a good time to use `cover?`.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F

I would also recommend that you store `Date.today` in a variable right before the start of your loop and use that in your comparison, instead of checking the current time on the server for every element in `@fscs`.

Also, it would be wise to use `Date.current` instead of `Date.today`. `Date.current` is a Rails method that’s time zone aware to give you today in the currently configured `Time.zone`.

Here’s an article I found helpful to learn about what methods to use and what methods to avoid, when dealing with all the fun that comes with time zones. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones

Comment: Those docs are great! thats what i was looking for to learn more about ranges! thanks for providing the link!

Comment: @ShawnWilson no problem!

Comment: @ShawnWilson I just updated my answer to mention time zones. It’s not relevant to the question you directly asked, but it is relevant to the code that you posted.

Comment: You know, it’s something I didn’t even think about. However time zone is somewhat important in trucking and now I need to rethink a few other items across the app. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Try doing something like this:

```
(fsc.activeDate..fsc.endDate).include?(Date.today)
```

You are trying to equate todays date with a range of dates whereas you want to check if the today's date is present in the date range.

Answer (score 2):

You still might use triple-equal aka case-equal FWIW. Just swap the arguments to `#===`: you need the one declared on `Range`, not the opposite one:

```
- Date.today === (fsc.activeDate..fsc.endDate)
+ (fsc.activeDate..fsc.endDate) === Date.today
```